# When (if ever) will HEAD~ and HEAD^ not be the same commit?

Tags: git

Is there any situation in which `HEAD~` and `HEAD^` will not be the same commit? In a more general sense, is there any series of merges or other operations that will result in `x~` not being the same thing as `x^`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, HEAD~ and HEAD^ are synonyms.

HEAD~ means HEAD~1 by definition.

HEAD~1 means HEAD^ by definition.

See [`git rev-parse --help`](http://man.he.net/man1/git-rev-parse) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

`HEAD~n` is the nth (grand) parent of a commit ( here HEAD) **following first parents**

`HEAD^n` is the nth parent of HEAD

Therefore,

`HEAD~` is the first parent of HEAD ( following first parents, which is moot here)

`HEAD^` is the first parent of HEAD

So, `HEAD~ = HEAD~1 = HEAD^1 = HEAD^.`

**They always point to the same commit.**

Note that by this, `HEAD~2 is equivalent to HEAD^^` and so on.

Comment: Shouldn't `HEAD~ = HEAD~1 = HEAD^n = HEAD^` be `HEAD~ = HEAD~1 = HEAD^1 = HEAD^` ?